# Laravel VueJS Address Validation RegExp not working

Tags: regex, laravel, vue.js, laravel-6, vee-validate

In my Laravel 6.18 project, I have setup VueJS with Webpack manager.

I am working on client-side validation for validating User's Street Address in an application form.

I am using VeeValidate library of VueJS for validations, where we can provide the RegExp along with `required` validations separated by `|` symbol.

Now when I try to use the Regex `[\w',-\\/.\s]` in the application form with necessary character escaping as below, it gives the error `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[\w'/: Unterminated character class` in the Browser's Console tab:

```
<input type="text"
    id="address"
    name="address"
    v-validate="'required|regex:^[\\w\'\,\-\/\.\\s]*$|max:75'"
    class="browser-default"
    required v-model="address"
    @blur="$emit('local-storage', 'address', address)"/>
<span class="missing-alert" v-show="errors.has('address')">Enter valid address</span>
```

Can anyone assist in understanding what's the syntactic error when using the said Regex inside Vue document textbox code ?

Comment: Try ``v-validate="'required|regex:/^[\\w\\/.\\',\\s-]*$/|max:75'"``

Comment: That's not working, same error..

Comment: Maybe `v-validate="'required|regex:/^[\\w\\/.\\x27,\\s-]*$/|max:75'"`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the other form for specifying your rules - an Object, like so:

```
v-validate="{ required: true, regex:/^[\\w\'\,\-\/\.\\s]*$/, max:75 }"
```